# How do I write for-loop statements in streams?

Tags: java

```
Map<String, Price> response = new HashMap<>();

    for(int i=0; i<price.getData().size(); i++){
        for(int j=0; j<exchangeRates.getData().size(); j++){
            if(priceOutput.getData().get(i).getTodayDate().isEqual(exchangeRates.getData().get(j).getTodayDate())){
                response.put(price.getData().get(i).getId(), price.getData().get(i));
            }
        }
    }
return response;
```

I have written this logic using for-loops statements,

Now how do I write the same piece of code using streams?

Comment: What have you tried? 
Also please see: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example
Please provide more code to make it easier to help :) Ex. The price and exchange rate variables are undefined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Stream#anyMatch`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#anyMatch-java.util.function.Predicate-) to filter based on another list. Something like this(not tested since I don't have the POJO)

```
List<Price> list1 = price.getData();
List<AnotherPojo> list2 =  exchangeRates.getData();

Map<String, Price> response = list1.stream()
                                    .filter(p -> list2.stream().anyMatch(e -> e.getTodayDate().isEqual(p.getTodayDate())))
                                    .collect(Collectors.toMap(p -> s1.getId(), p->p))
```

working test example:

```
List<String> list1 = Arrays.asList("A1", "B1", "C1", "D1");
List<String> list2 = Arrays.asList("A2", "B1", "C2", "D1");

Map<String, String> map = list1.stream()
    .filter(s1 -> list2.stream().anyMatch(s2 -> s2.equals(s1)))
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(s1 -> s1, s1 -> s1));

//output  {D1=D1, B1=B1}
```

Comment: @Newby: Additional info: Streams are often not faster than classic loops. They can look fancy and cool but might not always be the best fit in case or readability and performance - depence highly on amount of data.